# Deploy to Azure from GitHub error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, dnx

everyone.

I am trying to publish my web app to Azure, using [GitHub project (source)](https://github.com/SavaMinic/MessyLabAdmin) as Deployment Source in Azure portal.

Project is successfully fetched, but when the building starts, it fails in "Running deployment command...":

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\MessyLabAdmin\project.json...
Package Ix-Async 1.2.5 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Ix-Async 1.2.5 supports:
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile78)
Package Remotion.Linq 2.0.1 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Remotion.Linq 2.0.1 supports:
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 supports:
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7)
Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 is not compatible with dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.1.0-rc1-20151109-01 supports:
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile7)
One or more packages are incompatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
Committing restore...
Writing lock file to disk. Path:
D:\home\site\repository\src\MessyLabAdmin\project.lock.json
D:\home\site\repository\src\MessyLabAdmin\MessyLabAdmin.xproj
Restore failed in 13568ms.
```

Project runs completely fine in local environment, using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see references to RC1 in your project. RC2 just came out in mid-May, so I would suggest using RC2 going forward, since you posted this question right after RC2 was released.

As for deploying to Azure, here's what the ASP .NET Development blog current says on deploying to Azure:

> **Can I use RC2 with Azure Web Applications?**
>
> *We are rolling the RC2 out to the Azure App Services and expect it to become available later this week.  Keep an eye on the Azure Blog for
>   an announcement when it is available.*

**Source**: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/16/announcing-asp-net-core-rc2/

If you've already done a lot of work in RC1, here's a guide for migrating from RC1 to RC2:

- https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Migrating to RC2 is going to be pain in the a**, so probably won't do it.

I managed to publish to Azure directly from Visual Studio 2015 (update 2), by clicking: Build > Publish [project].